# Fedex-How to define SpecialServicesRequested SignatureOption for php-fedex-api-wrapper

Tags: php, fedex

I'm struggling to create a shipService Request with Signature option.
No matter what i send I always receive `[SignatureOption] => SERVICE_DEFAULT`, but I need to send with `[SignatureOption] => DIRECT`
I contacted the Fedex about this problem and they told me that U need to use SpecialServiceTypes for SignatureOption

I tried with this code

```
$packageLineItem1->setSequenceNumber( 1 )
        ->setItemDescription( 'Product TEST' )
        ->setSpecialServicesRequested( new ComplexType\PackageSpecialServicesRequested( [
        'SpecialServiceTypes'   => SimpleType\PackageSpecialServiceType::_SIGNATURE_OPTION,
        'SignatureOptionDetail' => new ComplexType\SignatureOptionDetail( [
        'OptionType' => SimpleType\SignatureOptionType::_DIRECT] 
                ),] ) )
```

And this one

```
$specialServiceRequested = new ComplexType\PackageSpecialServicesRequested();
$specialServiceRequested->setSpecialServiceTypes(SimpleType\PackageSpecialServiceType::_SIGNATURE_OPTION);
$specialServiceRequested->setSignatureOptionDetail( new ComplexType\SignatureOptionDetail( [
    'OptionType' => SimpleType\SignatureOptionType::_DIRECT,
] ));
$packageLineItem1->setSequenceNumber( 1 )
         ->setItemDescription( 'Product TEST' )
         ->setSpecialServicesRequested( $specialServiceRequested )
```

Comment: What type of shipment is involved? Looking at their API doc, it seems that the signature options are related to: `FedEx Express® and FedEx Ground` shipments, or possibly the _type_of shipment  (i.e. DIRECT is automatically selected for Dangerous Goods, if SERVICE_DEFAULT is used), and DIRECT does not apply if `hold at location` is used. It'll be Tuesday before I can check how we handle the signature options.

Comment: This Shipment is for Nederlands. I'm using ServiceType=PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, DropoffType=REGULAR_PICKUP

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info. What you have in the code examples _seems to be correct_, but I'll have to compare. Also, is this a shipment within the Nederlands, or from some other country to the Nederlands? (i.e. an international shipment?)

Comment: Hi Paul,
You are right. It seems that Fedex changed the Service types for Netherlands from PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT to FEDEX_PRIORITY

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the update! (the information may likely help other too!)